# PSQLException column of relation does not exists

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, archlinux

I try to save json equivalent to class `Album` to Postgres using Postman. I have created two entities for `Album` class and embedded object of `Album` class - `Duration` in Postgres. When I post json using Postman, IDE complains: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "hours" of relation "album" does not exist`, which is true, but `hours` should belong to field `duration` of `Album` not `Album` itself. Below is my code.

`Album` class:

```
package com.musesite.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name="album")
public class Album {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Embedded
    @Column(name="duration")
    private Duration duration;
    @Column(name="dateofrelease")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="CET")
    private Date dateOfRelease;
    @Column(name="coverpath")
    private String coverPath;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    public Date getDateOfRelease() {
        return dateOfRelease;
    }
    public void setDateOfRelease(Date dateOfRelease) {
        this.dateOfRelease = dateOfRelease;
    }
    public String getCoverPath() {
        return coverPath;
    }
    public void setCoverPath(String coverPath) {
        this.coverPath = coverPath;
    }
}
```

`Duration` class:

```
package com.musesite.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Embeddable
@Table(name="duration")
public class Duration {
    @Column(name="hours")
    private long hours;
    @Column(name="minutes")
    private long minutes;
    @Column(name="seconds")
    private long seconds;

    public long getHours() {
        return hours;
    }
    public void setHours(long hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }
    public long getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }
    public void setMinutes(long minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }
    public long getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }
    public void setSeconds(long seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }
}
```

How I created `duration` table in Postgres:

```
create table duration(
    hours int,
    minutes int,
    seconds int
);
```

How I created `album` table in Postgres:

```
create table album(
    title text,
    duration duration,
    dateofrelease date,
    coverpath text
);
```

JSON I send from Postman:

```
{
    "title": "Deftones",
    "duration": {"hours": 0, "minutes": 47, "seconds": 14 },
    "dateOfRelease": "20/05/2003",
    "coverPath": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/91/Deftones-selftitled_albumcover.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need only 1 `album` table.
The `@Embedded` annotation will convert the `hours, minutes, seconds` of the album table to a `Duration` class on java side, but duration does not have to exist in the database

```sql
create table album (
    id bigint primary key, -- this field was missing
    title text,
    dateofrelease date,
    coverpath text,
    hours int,
    minutes int,
    seconds int
);
```